# Authentication in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble figuring out how to authenticate a login to github to get data back in XML or JSON. This is the code I have right now:

```
import urllib2, sys, re, base64
url = "https://api.github.com/user"
username = "username"
password = "password"
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

I've been tinkering with this code that I found but I always seem to get an error that states, "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized."

I'm positive that my login info is correct and I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: this line looks wrong `pass.add_password ...`. `pass` is a reserved word in python.

Comment: It should be `passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)`

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639538/python-log-in-a-website-using-urllib

Comment: Sorry, typo, it should say passman